# How to create a List from user defined Classes

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I am new to Stackoverflow so ignore the mistakes. I have different user defined classes which have  number of attributes. I want to create a List with the use of these classes and need to use system define datatype instead of user define classes...
Here is the code you can better understand with it.

Here are the classes

```
public class Slide
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
//.........
public class SubSection
{
    public SubSection() 
    { 
        this.Composition = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Composition { get; set; }

}
//................
public class Section
{
    public Section()
    {
        this.SubSections = new List<SubSection>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public List<SubSection> SubSections { get; set; }
}
```

Every Node in the list should have section,subsection and slide

Comment: "need to use system define datatype instead of user define classes"... not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: What are the user defined classes, and what are the system data types? This code example doesn't make it obvious what you're trying to do, perhaps you could provide some more information?

Comment: Also, which version of .NET/C# are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you need a list, where every element in the list contains one of each of the classes you've listed in your question. You can use a List of [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
var mylist = new List<Tuple<Section, SubSection, Slide>>();
mylist.Add(Tuple.Create(new Section(), new SubSection(), new Slide());
mylist.Add(Tuple.Create(new Section(), new SubSection(), new Slide());
mylist.Add(Tuple.Create(new Section(), new SubSection(), new Slide());
```

Tuples were introduced in .NET 4.5, so as long as you're on at least 4.5, this will work for you.

Comment: Are Tuples actually favourable to concrete classes? I've used them before for this sort of thing, but its not the most readable/maintainable code.

Comment: @Arkiliknam I'd generally create my own class unless it was something internal. OP mentioned system defined types though, so I went for something in the standard library, guessing that's what OP meant.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Good call then :)

Comment: @Arkiliknam it's pretty convenient in F# :)

Comment: @Jwosty I also use tuples quite a lot in python, nice for throwing around arbitrary immutable collections.

Comment: I tend to use Anonymous types more than Tuples, as long as its all internal functionality.

Comment: @Arkiliknam if C# had a nice tuple syntax, it would probably be used more

Answer (score 0):

First create a model class with all your data you want to include and after that you can create list of that class.

```
public class CustomClass
{
   public Section{get;set;}
   public SubSection{get;set;}
   public Slide{get;set;}
}

var customClasses = new List<CustomClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Josh Smeaton's answer of Tuples, but for fun I wonder if you could consider Anonymous Types as a System Defined Type...?

```
var myList = new[]
{
    new { Section = new Section(), SubSection = new SubSection(), Slide = new Slide()}, 
    new { Section = new Section(), SubSection = new SubSection(), Slide = new Slide()}
}.ToList();
```

Comment: hah, I had added anonymous types into my answer as a second option, but removed them. Only useful in local scopes, but still a good idea to show them.